# How to click on an <li> element with javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, uiwebview

Assuming that we have html like the one below, I want to be able to click on the element using javascript just as if I it was a link.

```
<li class="myClass" data-type="onClick" data-target="something://url">
    <img src="img.png" alt="image"/>
    <h2> Text</h2>
</li>
```

Thanks

Comment: just add `onclick="some_function();"` to your `li` tag?

Comment: Just a note (may save from styling issues in the future), there's an extra space in front of your text in the `h2` element.  If you want padding, add `.myClass h2{padding-left:3px;}` to your css.

Comment: @Beez That space character has no effect on the presentation of the H2 element.

Comment: Really?  I didn't realize h2 elements ignored white-space...I'll have to read the spec, now.  Thanks, @Vidas

Comment: H'm. Doesn't say anything about it.  Well, it appears [you're right](http://jsfiddle.net/rRNDy/), still.  I thought it only ignored spaces > 1.  Good to know! Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
<li class="myClass" onclick="doSomething()">
    <img src="img.png" alt="image"/>
    <h2> Text</h2>
</li>
```

In your javascript create the function doSomething()

And maybe use CSS on the li element:

```
li.myClass {
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use jQuery. It's more easy to work with jQuery. There you would give the li element an id or a class and then you could use this code:

```
$(".myClass").click( function() {
 // .. do the code
});
```

or with id:

```
$("#myID").click( function() {
 // .. do the code
});
```

I would also advise to put a pointer on the element by adding " cursor: pointer; " to the css.
So everyone knows it's possible to click on it :)